# why are files and directories with space in their names ignored in bash?

Tags: bash, recursion, space

I have a script, which is supposed to go through directories and subdirectories of where it gets executed and search for specific file types, say pdf, and delete them and then creates an empty file with the deleted file's name. 
It works fine except that it ignores files and folders, which contain space(s) in their names.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
#  Created by User on 6/20/11.
#

dir=./
for files in $(find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90);
do
echo $files
rm -fR $files
touch $files.removed
done
```

Can any one suggest a solution how to make this script taking care of all files and folders with any kind of name?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `IFS` causes word splitting upon encountering spaces.  Say:

```
for files in $(IFS=$'\n' find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90);
```

Saying `IFS=$'\n'` above would cause word splitting to happen only on newlines, so filenames with spaces would work well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having your script this way and use double quotes:

```
dir=./
while read files
do
   echo "$files"
   rm -fR "$files"
   touch "$files".removed
done < <(find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did ask about *any* name. A legal file name can include a linefeed, so any solution that assumes a linefeed separates two file names is not quite correct. The only two characters that cannot appear in a file name are `/` (which is used to separate path components) and the null character.

If your version of `find` supports it, you can get a null-separated list of file names using

```
find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90 -print0
```

To process this, you'll need `xargs`:

```
find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90 -print0 |
  xargs -0 -I %% sh -c 'echo "%%"; rm -fR "%%"; touch "%%.removed"'
```

If your `find` does not support `-print0`, you can use the `-exec` primary much like `xargs`:

```
find -L "$dir" -name '*.pdf' -mtime +90 -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"; rm -fR "{}"; touch "{}.removed"'
```